How to read multiple excel files, convert them to separate csv files without hardcoding FileName & Path in Python
I am new to Python and seeking your help to solve the below problem.
I have a Portal where users upload files. The files gets stored into the directory (/input_files/test1.xlsx). There can be multiple files like test1.xlsx, test2.xlsx, test3.xlsx, etc.
I need to convert these files into CSV and store them in a separate directory, which I did using the below code 
import pandas as pd

file_path = "/Users/input_files/"

read_file = pd.read_excel(file_path + "test1.xlsx")

read_file.to_csv(file_path + "input_csv_files/test1.csv", index = None, header = True)`

My desired output is 
/input_files/test1.xlsx --> /input_files/input_csv_files/test1.csv 
/input_files/test2.xlsx --> /input_files/input_csv_files/test2.csv 
/input_files/test3.xlsx --> /input_files/input_csv_files/test3.csv .... & so on
I have achieved it for one file but I want to get rid of HardCoded File name. I need the code to read all the .xlsx files in the directory and convert them to .csv files separately as shown above dynamically. 
Appreciate your help!

Research os.listdir and the glob and pathlib modules.

Here is a straightforward solution to set you started:
import os
import pandas as pd

source_directory = "/input_files/"
output_directory = os.path.join(source_directory, "input_csv_files")

all_files = [file for file in os.listdir(source_directory) if file.endswith(".xlsx")]

for filename in all_files:
    input_filepath = os.path.join(source_directory, filename)
    read_file = pd.read_excel(input_filepath)
    
    output_filepath = os.path.join(output_directory, os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + ".csv")
    read_file.to_csv(output_filepath, index=None, header=True)

Then you can improve it depending on your use case.

This is exactly what I was looking for!! Thank you! @duartedb
It works. I also used the below code to copy the files to S3.
                   ``` s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
                    bucket = "mybucket-redshift-spectrum"
                    s3_tgt_dir = "s3-input-bucket/"
                    s3.Bucket(bucket).upload_file(output_filepath, s3_tgt_dir + os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + ".csv")```

